# PSP screen doesn't turn on but the rest of the system is working

Tags: technical-issues, psp

When I turn on my PSP, the green light turns on, it makes sounds, and when I press buttons on it, it makes moving around the menu sounds. But it doesn't display anything on the screen.

I've ordered a replacement screen and replaced it, but the screen still doesn't turn on.

What could be wrong with it? I don't wanna just give up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I replaced the screen too. But it wasnt working. I took it to the shop where I bought it. He fixed it and the new screen started working.

If you have replaced the screen yourself, I would recommend you should take it to a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PSP is it?

If it's sufficiently recent, you can use [a special cable](http://www.fatgamer.com/p-5613-tv-link-for-psp.aspx) to send output from the PSP to a nice widescreen TV.

I picked one up a couple years back and it's been excellent for UMD videos and games where a slightly bigger screen and sound system (yeah, I'm looking at you Rock Band!) can be helpful.

Anyway, point being this: If you can output to a TV screen, then you know that at least the PSP is generating a solid video signal.  So if it's not the screen itself (already replaced you said) and it's not simply a "brightness level" thing (I assume you've futzed with the buttons) and if the cable works then obviously it's the connection between the screen and the video signal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this habit of turning off the display by holding the brightness button(while listening to some music) and dozing off with out turning off the console properly(pretty much every day). Until one day, it gave me a nasty surprise - it didn't turn on at all, if I recall correctly, the speakers were okay. And on one night, I looked at the screen real close and noticed that the display is actually visible but it was incredibly dull.
I finally got it fixed although I don't remember whether or not the screen was replaced but judging by the 30$(~Rs.1450) I had to pay - I guess it was.
I'm assuming that your issue is similar to mine, when you get it fixed (get it to a service center) make a habit to turn it off properly.